# Golang Postgres connection string not opening return null

Tags: postgresql, go

I am sure that there is something with the connectionString as the values I am giving are the same values that I use in Java to log into the same database. This is my code

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "log"
)




func main() {


    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=password dbname=name sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

     defer db.Close()
    age := 21
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT city FROM streams WHERE id=69", age)

    fmt.Println(rows)

}
```

I am using what I found here https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq my postgres version is 9.4 and my Go Version is 1.6 . I have no idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you add the ping code and see what error is returned?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"

    "log"
)

func main() {

    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", "user=postgres password=password dbname=name sslmode=disable")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()
    age := 21
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT city FROM streams WHERE id=$1", age)

    fmt.Println(rows)

}
```

Comment: Thank you it was the lack of the dollar sign that gave out the nil.

Answer (score 1):

Your

```
 rows, err := db.Query("SELECT city FROM streams WHERE id=69", age)
```

has to be:

```
 rows, err := db.Query("SELECT city FROM streams WHERE id = ?", age)
```

also

```
 defer db.Close()
```

goes after you execute the query.

Comment: Thank you that helped towards the answer.